# Magento checkout stuck due to invoice increment id integrity

Tags: magento, checkout

Few days ago Magento checkout page had been stuck, customer was not able to proceed any order due to integrity constraint violation then increase the invoice increment id through database.

[image]

I checked log file then came to know , this would be happen due to paypal transaction failed but not sure.

If yes , What would be permanent solution for this, this issue will not occur again on website.'

Kindly help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: This could be resolve by programming that's why i post this question over here

Comment: can you try disable the paypal and check with other payment methods , also check with magento default theme once.....

Comment: It is not happened every failed transaction of Paypal as i tried multiple times. But checkout page has stuck after that a failed transaction.

Comment: Many things could be resolved by programming, but that doesn't make the question about programming. Just because software is programmed and your question is about software it just doesn't mean your question is about programming.